eth_sendTransaction is not supported. Use eth_sendRawTransaction to send a signed transaction
I'll go straight to the point.
I have a React App, I want to integrate this web with a very simple smart contract, which receives a hash and then saves with an event the timestamp of when it was received:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >= 0.8.0;

contract hashContract {
  mapping(string => uint256) private hashRegistry;
  address private owner;

  constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  event logFunctionUsage(uint256 timestamp);

  function registerEvidence(string memory receiveHash) public isOwner {
    hashRegistry[receiveHash] = block.timestamp;
    emit logFunctionUsage(block.timestamp);
  }

  modifier isOwner() {
    require(owner == msg.sender);
    _;
  }
}

I'm having two errors when integrating, first is "Eip1559NotSupportedError: Invalid value given "Eip1559NotSupportedError". Error: Network doesn't support eip-1559", which I found is fixed by adding "gasPrice: value". Here is the code of the integration:
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const hashContractABI = require('../contracts/hashContract.json');
const SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

class EthereumService {
  constructor() {
    this.web3 = new Web3(process.env.REACT_APP_WEB3_URL); //This is the IP of my node
    this.contractAddress = process.env.REACT_APP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS; //This is the address of my smart contract
    this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(
      hashContractABI.abi,
      this.contractAddress,
    );
  }

  async registerEvidence(data) {
    try {
      const hashedData = SHA256(data).toString();
      await this.contract.methods
        .registerEvidence(hashedData)
        .send({
          from: process.env.REACT_APP_EVIDENCE_FROM, //This is the ID of my metamask wallet
          gas: 200000,
          gasPrice: 1000000,
        })
        .then((receipt) => {
          console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating data and registering evidence:', error);
    }
  }
}

export const ethereumService = new EthereumService();

But then this is now giving "The method eth_sendTransaction is not supported. Use eth_sendRawTransaction to send a signed transaction" error, but I don't really understand the documentation with those examples so I'm unsure of what to do anymore.
The network I am deploying and intending to perform this operation on is Alastria B Network, which I'm told works just like any other Ethereum based network. This network doesn't charge gas for the performed operations, so maybe I should set "gas" and "gasPrice" at value "0"?
If I'm missing any information let me know so I can update with it.
Thanks to anyone who could point me in the right direction with this.

If it is a 3rd party node that you are connecting to you need to locally sign, and then send the transaction, sendTransaction needs your key to be managed by the node so external endpoints don't support it.. No idea about Alastria specifically, but eip1559 transactions have maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas, legacy have gasPrice.

The node is mine, which Alastria have permissioned in their network, so when connecting to this node I then connect to their network through it. I think I understand what you mean, I will try to find examples in which the transaction is first signed and then sent, hopefully I understand them. I will also have a look at the difference between eip1559 and legacy as it is something I didn't know about. Thanks for the pointers.

Brilliant, if it is your node you can potentially unlock the account to use that method, you would also (at least in the case of geth) have to start the execution engine with with the deprecated --personal flag to expose the account management namespace. personal_unlockAccount > account can be used with eth_sign and eth_sendTransaction while unlocked. I never do this personally, preferring to manage the keys, sign and then send explicitly. Have many examples of signing and sending in web3 using python here: https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py/blob/main/v3exactOutputSingle.py#L65

Thanks for the link, I suppose that the python code can be converted to javascript so I will have a look at this too and hopefully manage to find a solution. I will update this post the following days in case something similar becomes a question for someone else.

Sounds good, and yes it should be easy to convert with a js web3 library. Many of the early python examples were ports from js, as it has historically been more widely used in web3.
